# nginx GET .php variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, php

I have a bunch of PHP files that take .php?id=123 and I need to get them all. How do I do them all in my config file?

I can't seem to figure out how to make use of

```
get1.php?id=stuff
get2.php?id=stuff
get3.php?id=stuff
```

and so on...

The problem is how do I do that when they are all under the same root directory?

---

**With the following I get 500 ERROR on the p.php?id=945 but PHP works fine but I CANT login or get POST data to work**

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name site.com www.site.com;
      root /home/site/public_html;
      location / {
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
      location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso)$ {
      expires 1d;
      try_files $uri?$args @backend;
      }
      error_page 405 = @backend;
      add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
      }
      location @backend {
      internal;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
      }
      location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
        try_files $uri?$args /index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
      }
      location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
      }
    }
```

THIS: just 500s
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/site/public_html;

    #try and serve static files directly
    location ~* ^[^\?\&]+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
        try_files $uri @inPlaceDynamicFile;
        expires 24h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    #allow us to have dynamic css/js files
    location @inPlaceDynamicFile {
        # examples /css/cssIncludes.css => /css/cssIncludes.css.php
        try_files $uri.php =404;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        include       fastcgi_params.conf;
    }

    location  / {
        try_files $uri?$args /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw the line /\.ht should probably be "location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }" to block all 'hidden' files

Answer (score 0):

> "Is this correct?"

Nope.

1) Root should never be in a location block, it should only be in a server block.

2) Apache rewrite for testing if something is an existing file is done with try_files not with Nginx rewrite. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088663/apache-mod-rewrite-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/16095173#16095173)

3) Your proxy_pass is going to be passing through to the same server which has got to be a circular redirect.

4) You've also got a location block inside a location block, which seems quite odd. Although that may be needed for some advanced config, you don't need it for what you're doing.

I think you probably want you nginx conf to be like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /home/site/public_html;

    #try and serve static files directly
    location ~* ^[^\?\&]+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
        try_files $uri @inPlaceDynamicFile;
        expires 24h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    #allow us to have dynamic css/js files
    location @inPlaceDynamicFile {
        # examples /css/cssIncludes.css => /css/cssIncludes.css.php
        try_files $uri.php =404;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include       fastcgi_params.conf;
    }

    location  / {
        try_files $uri /p.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params.conf;
    }
}
```

If you do want the only requests that contain .php to go to your `p.php` file then you should replace the last location block with:

```
location  ~ /(.*)\.php {
    try_files $uri /p.php?q=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include       fastcgi_params.conf;
}

location  / {
    try_files /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include       fastcgi_params.conf;
}
```

*Edit*

> Do I need to create specific rewrites for EVERY php file that has a
>   $_GET[''];?

No - you should be able to pass them in to any file with the try_files like:

```
location  / {
        try_files $uri?$args /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params.conf;
    }
```

That would match any .php request to a php file if it exists with the query string appended , and then fall back to index.php if the .php file doesn't exist with both the query string and path passed in.

Comment: Do I need to create specific rewrites for EVERY php file that has a $_GET[''];?. Now that I look this really is not so much a .htaccess issue as it is a GET with the PHP files