# Problems moving Sites from Apache to Nginx (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am migrating some vhosts from apache to nginx. Unfortunately i am having some troubles because of .htaccess files from the apache instance.

Here is the situation (apache):

The DocumentRoot has different folders with projects inside. I could access most of them (through `www.example.com/appname`) without problems.

But on accessing (the main page) `www.example.com` the following `.htaccess` file redirects the users.

/var/www/html/.htaccess:

`Redirect /index.html https://example.com/example/`

Which then has another .htaccess in /var/www/html/example/.htaccess

`Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */* 
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ web/$1`

So then the next .htaccess in /var/www/html/example/web

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php`

How can i translate this to an nginx location block or blocks ? I can't seem to get it right. On my last check the client browser said that something is wrong with redirecting. Here is the nginx vhost config:

Please keep in mind that there are still some tries i found, but so far i didn't have any luck. Help would be really appreciated !

thank you guys

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  listen 80;

  root   /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  access_log /dev/stdout;
  error_log /dev/stdout info;

  # FIRST .htaccess FILE
  # redirect index.html to example.com/example
  # the first line seems to have worked, the 2nd one is not yet tested
  location /index.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/example/ redirect; }
  location /index.html { return $301 $scheme:http://example.com/example/$request_uri; }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /index.html;
    #try_files $uri /index.php?$args /index.html;
  }

  location /example {
    root /var/www/html;

    # try_files options: 
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    # try_files $uri /index.php?url=$request_uri;

    # SECOND .htaccess FILE
    rewrite ^/(.+)?$ /web/$1;

    location /example/web {
      # THIRD .htaccess FILE

      # option 1
      # if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php; }

      # option 2
      #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.php last;

      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }


  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # ocurs with nginx's one
  #
  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny  all;
  }
}
```

Comment: "the client browser said that something is wrong with redirecting" - could you post the error message?

Comment: there's a lot going on in that config. if i were you, i would remove all those `location` blocks and then re-add them one by one, and test to make sure it's doing what I expect at each stage before adding more

Answer (score 1):

check this out: [Apache mod_rewrite to Nginx rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088663/apache-mod-rewrite-to-nginx-rewrite-rules).
basically, apache rewrite and nginx rewrite do not quite mean the same thing. it seems that you are using nginx `rewrite` where you should be using nginx `try_files`. 
so, you might try doing

```
try_files /web/$uri /web/$uri/ /web/index.php?$args
```

instead of

```
rewrite ^/(.+)?$ /web/$1;
```